# Python Selenium Actions into Playwirght

Tags: python, playwright

I'm trying to convert my code from selenium to playwright and having a hard time finding a solution on how to convert the actions from selenium to playwright.

Here is selenium code

```
    dob = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@name="dob"]')
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    actions.click(dob)
    actions.perform()
```

I need to convert this to playwight but it's not working.

This is what i've tried.

```
page.click('//*[@name="dob"]')
```

Also, tried, dblclick, focus nothing seems to work. When the browser clicks on this input field a few css changes happen in dom.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright has a built in code generator which will make things easy for you.

Run this command and try it out

```
npx playwright codegen
```

Comment: tried that it gave me the page.click... but that doesn't work on the page in question. The only way i had to do that in the past was to use the selenium actions.